# Specflow - Am I missing msi?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, bdd, specflow, specrun

I have a specflow test which is running well in my Visual studio environment. I am using specrun to run those test. All is fine.

The challenge is I need to run these test in another machine where I dont have Visual Studio to run the tests.

I believe we can install specflow ( assume it is available as an MSI ) and then run the runtests.cmd which is available by default.

But I dont know from where I need to get this msi. Can anyone help me in this regard

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The installation process is described at http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Installation/

Comment: Thanks for that. I am aware of this. I am looking forward for a msi like NUnit.exe or similar which is independednt of VS. Is there any msi which I am missing.

Comment: Specflow doesn't actually run the tests. Instead NUnit (by default, but may also be mstest) run tests and SpecFlow sits in the middle. So yes, you may need to download nUnit from http://nunit.org/ too.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Specrun which is the runner you should be able to find the files in the pacakges directory if you are using Nuget